# ValueError: Input 0 of layer global_average_pooling2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 128]

Tags: python, tensorflow2

I load the saved model and for finetuning reason I add classification layers to the output of loaded model, So this what I write :

```
def create_keras_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', compile=False)
    resnet_output = model.output
    layer1 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnet_output)
    layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, use_bias=False, name='nonlinear')(layer1)
    model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, use_bias=False, name='output', activation='relu')(layer2)
    model = tf.keras.Model(model.input, model_output)
    return model
```

but I find this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer global_average_pooling2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 128]
```

Can anyone please help me and tell me from what this error and how can I resolve this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could have answered better if you would have shared `model.h5` architecture or the last layer of the `model.h5`.

In your case the input dimension is `2` where as `tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()` expects input dimension of `4`.

As per [tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling2D) documentation, the tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D layer expects below input shape -

> **Input shape:** If `data_format='channels_last'`: 4D tensor with shape
> `(batch_size, rows, cols, channels)`. If `data_format='channels_first'`:
> 4D tensor with shape `(batch_size, channels, rows, cols)`.

In this [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning), you will learn how to classify images of cats and dogs by using transfer learning from a pre-trained network along with fine-tuning.